# ColdFusion ORM Caching "Read-only"

Tags: hibernate, caching, orm, coldfusion

I am a little confused about how ORM caching works with respects to the caching strategys. If I am to use the "Read-Only" caching strategy, does this mean if I load an entity and try to edit it, I wont be able to?

If thats true, then how would I go about editing that entity?

Comment: For that you would need to use a different caching strategy I wrote a little more on it here: http://www.samfarmer.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/7/The-one-where-I-try-ColdFusion-9-ORM-secondary-cache-and-decide-its-awesome

Comment: Thanks Sam, thats a wicked post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> read-only Only works with data that will not be updated. Produces an error if you attempt to update or insert records.

http://java.dzone.com/news/one-where-i-try-coldfusion-9

I guess if you've updated the entity in the DB, u might need to do an `ORMEvictEntity('entity')`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSCAD9638E-2D2C-48d8-9069-AE5A220B75A6.html

Comment: Okay perfect, just what I needed to know. Thanks